# Symfony2 Sonata Classification Bundle Extends

Tags: symfony, sonata

I installed Sonata Classification bundle (part of Sonata Project Sandbox) which include Categories, Tags and Collections. Now I need create custom categories class, for example Categories for Restaurants, which should be identical to the Categories, but must contain several custom options, and save all data to another mysql table.

I can't do it in Application folder because I can't override some config files, such as routes and admin.xml, because of DI. Vendor\Sonata\ClassificationBundle have DI folder, and configs connects through Dependency Injection. I can't override it in Applications folder.

How can I perform this task??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot do this with doctrine, then you cannot do that with SonataAdminBundle.